# How to pass "pointer to a pointer" to a function that expects "pointer to array"

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Consider this piece of code:

```
#define MAX 4
............
............ 
int** ptr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*MAX);
*ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*MAX);
// Assigned values to the pointer successfully
```

How `foo()` can be invoked with `ptr` as parameter ? `foo()`'s prototype has been declared as below:

```
void foo(int arr[][MAX]);
```

Comment: `foo` parameters seems to be necessary another.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14549030/399317

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `foo parameters seems to be necessary another` What on earth that means BLUEPIXY?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture  because size of arr is uncertain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass `ptr` as parameter to that `foo` function.

The memory layout of a 2-dimensional array (array of arrays) is quite different from that of an array of pointers to arrays.

Either change the function signature to accept a `int**` (and probably also size information), or define `ptr` to be a 2-dimensional array of the appropriate size.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume the function `foo` in your example actually wants a 2-D array of `int`, with `MAX` columns and an unspecified number of rows.  This works in C and C++ because of how the rows lay out in memory.  All the elements in row N+1 appear contiguously after all the elements in row N.

The syntax `int arr[][MAX]` asks for a pointer to the first element of such a 2-D array, not an array of pointers to rows.  I'll assume you want the 2-D array, and *not* an array of pointers.

First, you need to correctly allocate your elements.  You haven't specified what the leftmost dimension of `arr[][MAX]` is, or where it comes from.  I'll assume it's in the variable `dim` here:

```
int (*ptr)[MAX];  /* pointer first element of an int[][MAX] array */

/* Allocate a 2-D array of dim * MAX ints */
ptr = (int (*)[MAX]) malloc( dim * MAX * sizeof(int) );
```

Then, to call your function, just do `foo( ptr )` and it'll work without errors or warnings.

To make your code cleaner (especially if you're using many of these 2-D arrays), you might consider wrapping the pointer type in a `typedef`, and writing a small function to allocate these arrays.

```
typedef int (*int_array_2d)[MAX];

int_array_2d alloc_int_array_2d( int dim1 )
{
    return (int_array_2d) malloc( dim1 * MAX * sizeof(int) );
}
```

That way, elsewhere in your code, you can say something much simpler and cleaner:

```
int_array_2d ptr = alloc_int_array_2d( dim );
```

Use the type system to your advantage. The C and C++ syntax for the type and the typecast are ugly, and unfamiliar to most people.  They look strange due to the precedence of `*` vs. `[]`.  If you hide it in a `typedef` though, it can help keep you focused on what you're trying to do, rather than understanding C/C++'s weird precedence issues that arise when you mix arrays and pointers.