# Issue with variable as dimension to 2-D array in C++

Tags: c++

Following code runs fine -

```
void func(int m[][2])
{
    cout<<(m[0][0])<<endl;
}

int main()
{
//    int x=2;
    int m[2][2];
    m[0][0] = m[0][1] = m[1][0] = m[1][1] = 5;
    cout<<m[0][0]<<endl;
    func(m);
}
```

But when I change `main()` as follows -

```
int main()
{
    int x=2;
    int m[x][x];
    m[0][0] = m[0][1] = m[1][0] = m[1][1] = 5;
    cout<<m[0][0]<<endl;
    func(m);
}
```

I get the error message -

`try.cpp:16:11: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[(((long unsigned int)(((long int)x) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)]’ to ‘int (*)[2]’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void func(int (*)[2])’`

Also, the following runs fine -

```
int main()
{
    int x=2;
    int m[x][x];
    m[0][0] = m[0][1] = m[1][0] = m[1][1] = 5;
    cout<<m[0][0]<<endl;
    //func(m);
}
```

Can anyone explain the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming `gcc` then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548753/passing-a-multidimensional-variable-length-array-to-a-function) may provide an answer although it is not a nice one.

Comment: Your second and last are not standard C++.

Comment: @chris true but `gcc` and `clang` at least support VLA as an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable length arrays are not valid in C++. g++ allows this as an "extension".

```
int x=2;
int m[x][x];    //Illegal in C++
```

You should go for **Dynamic Memory allocation** if you want to dynamically allocate memory to an array.

```
int x=2;
int *m = new int[x];
```

It is better if you use STL :

```
int x = 10;
std::vector<int> m(n);
```

Or you can use *const* not a *variable* when creating it.

```
const int x=2;             //it's a compile time constant
int m[x][x];
```

Comment: Alternatively you should recommend the OP to use [tag:c++] STL containers instead of 'raw' [tag:c] arrays, to overcome all the obstacles with managing memory allocation on your own.