# 2d arrays in recursion in c

Tags: c, recursion

Well, This is the piece of code i wrote to print a matrix in spiral form in c. But it started showing me an error during compilation. i,basically, don't know how to write recursive functions properly. can someone fix the code ? please..
the error in this code was that
solution.c:23:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
can anyone tell me what that means...

```
     #include <stdio.h>

     matrix(int B[20][20],int M,int N);

     main() 
     {
     int M,N,j,i=1;
     scanf("%d %d",&M,&N);
    int B[M][N];

    for(i=1; i<=M; i++)
    {
    for(j=1; j<=N; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&B[i][j]);
    }
    }

    matrix(B[20][20],M,N); 
    return 0; 
    }
    matrix(int B[20][20], int M,int N);
    {
    while(M!=0||N!=0)
    { 
    for (i=1,j=1; j<=N; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",(B[i][j]));
    } 
    for(i=2,j=N; i<=M; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",(B[i][j])); 
    }
    for(i=M,j=N-1; j>0; j--)
    {
        printf("%d ",(B[i][j]));
    } 
    for(i=M-1,j=1; i<=2; i--)
    {
        printf("%d ",(B[i][j])); 
    } 
   }
    matrix(B[20][20],--M,--N); 
   }
```

Comment: what is it meant to be doing? what errors are you getting?

Comment: solution.c:35:8: error: unknown type name 'B'
 matrix(B[20][20],M,N);
        ^
solution.c:35:18: error: unknown type name 'M'
 matrix(B[20][20],M,N);
                  ^
solution.c:35:20: error: unknown type name 'N'
 matrix(B[20][20],M,N);
                    ^
solution.c:37:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token
 {

Comment: These are the errors it was showing.I don't know what to do. can you help me

Comment: main need to look like this: void main() { /*..*/ }
or int main() { /*..*/ return 0; }

Comment: I want it to print a matrix in a spiral form

Comment: `main()` at **least** shall return `int`! @eitank

Comment: the error is with the function matrix.

Comment: Please update your question, if you want to add something to it! Do not squezze it into comments.

Comment: @eitank i hate this form, but it's valid, unfortunately. compiler will add `int` before `main()`.

Comment: i did this once.recursive is a good way to write it, but you will have to calculate the step yourself. you will need a help function to act as an actuator and it needs more info than you give now.

Comment: Maybe indent the code properly first. As alk mentioned, a valid declaration of main is `int main()`, and an appropriate `return` is necessary at the end of it. You also shouldn't declare `int B[M][N];` rather `int B[20][20];`, so the function at least has a chance to take it right. In the function call, the dimensions select a member, not the entire array as intended (pass just `B`). The loops should go from 0, to `<M` and `<N` since the first member of an array is the 0th. Maybe it will work slightly better after going through these...

Answer (score 1):

I will try and address the issues at hand while giving you a recursive solution for your problem.

**typing**: C is a [static typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language#Typed_versus_untyped_languages) language which requires you to give all variables **AND** function declarations a type. This lead your first compile errors.

```
matrix(int B[20][20],int M,int N);
//should have been (though be careful there is another issue addressed later)
void matrix(int B[20][20],int M,int N);
```

as well as

```
 main() {
 //shoud have been
 int main() {
```

**counting**: as a programmer you should get used to start counting at 0 as most languages do so. An array of size 4 has the elements `array[0] array[1] array[2] array[3]`. Trying to access an address above `size-1` will lead to undefined behavior.

Therefore every loop you had would have given you unintended behavior

```
for(i=1; i <= M; i++)
//should have been (as an example)
for(i=0; i <  M; i++)
```

**array as a parameter I**: if you want to pass an array as a parameter you have give just the variable name as any `[X][Y]` would be an access to the array and result in the element stored at that location being passed instead of the intended array.

```
matrix(B[20][20],--M,--N); 
//should have been
matrix(B,--M,--N);
```

**array as a parameter II**: if you want a function to take an array as a parameter you have to declare the function head in a specific way. Which is quite counter intuitive. You can read more on that topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548753/passing-a-multidimensional-variable-length-array-to-a-function). But in the end

```
void matrix(int B[20][20],int M,int N);
//should have been
void matrix(int M,int N,int B[][N]);
```

**scope**: Local variables just have a [limited scope](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm) therefore

```
    void matrix(int B[20][20], int M,int N) {
      while(M!=0||N!=0) { 
        for (i=1,j=1; j<=N; j++)
          { /*....*/
```

cannot work as either `i` and `j` are unknown in this function. This would be correct:

```
    void matrix(int B[20][20], int M,int N) {
      int i,j;
      while(M!=0||N!=0) { 
        for (i=1,j=1; j<=N; j++)
          { /*....*/
```

**while-loop**: The while loop will end as soon as the head of the loop evaluates to false

```
   while(M!=0||N!=0)
    { 
     /*stuff*/
    }
```

would have therefore resulted in an endless loop, as neither `M` nor `N` are changed in the body. Or it would have just never been executed.

**recursion**: You did write a (theoretically) recursive function, though without any aboard rule. A recursion is nothing but a loop and therefore it carries on until an aboard/break is issued. Basically speaking you have to have something like

```
  if(/*aboard_condition*/) return;
```

to ensure that your recursion will end at some point .

**semicolons**: addressing the part of your question

> solution.c:23:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token

you just had a semicolon to much:

```
matrix(int B[20][20],int M,int N);
{ ....
//should have been (though do not forget about the other issues)
matrix(int B[20][20],int M,int N)
{
```

as a semicolon seperated the function header from the function block

As your print function was quite broken I used a print_sprial function borrowed from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form/) and turned it into a recursive one by taking the variables `m`  and `n` out of the body and into the header. I further moved the print function in front of the main function to avoid having to give a header declaration.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_matrix(int matrix_y, int matrix_x, int a[matrix_y][matrix_x],int k,int l)
{
    int i;
    int m = matrix_y;
    int n = matrix_x;
    /*  k - starting row index
        m - ending row index
        l - starting column index
        n - ending column index
        i - iterator
    */

    while (k < m && l < n)
    {
        /* Print the first row from the remaining rows */
        for (i = l; i < n; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[k][i]);
        }
        k++;

        /* Print the last column from the remaining columns */
        for (i = k; i < m; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i][n-1]);
        }
        n--;

        /* Print the last row from the remaining rows */
        if ( k < m)
        {
            for (i = n-1; i >= l; --i)
            {
                printf("%d ", a[m-1][i]);
            }
            m--;
        }

        /* Print the first column from the remaining columns */
        if (l < n)
        {
            for (i = m-1; i >= k; --i)
            {
                printf("%d ", a[i][l]);
            }
            l++;    
        }        
    }
}

int main()
{
    int M,N,j,i=1;
    scanf("%d %d",&M,&N);
    int B[M][N];

    for(i=0; i != M; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j != N; j++)
        {
            printf("%d/%d:",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&B[i][j]);
        }
    }

    print_matrix(M,N,B,0,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As we got into the problem, your matrix dimensions depends on user's choice. Therefor, you wouldn't be able to allocate your matrix in the stack using the following code:

```
int B[N][M];
```

because the dimensions aren't known in compilation time. so it required to use malloc.

The code using malloc:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void doSomething(int** matrix, int size0, int size1);

int main() {
    int rows, cols, i, j;
    int **matrix;
    // scanf for row, cols

    // allocate matrix (basically using malloc)
    matrix = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
    }

    // scanf for matrix values

    // call recursive function
    doSomething(matrix, rows, cols);

    // free in reverse order
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);

    return 0;
}

void doSomething(int** matrix, int size0, int size1) {
    int i,j;
    // stop condition

    // some code here

}
```

Comment: in doSomething() function I want to increment row and column count where column count increment is random. What should I do then?

Answer (score -1):

> BETTER SOLUTION

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,flag=0;
    int function_Matrix(int arr[][4],int i,int j)
    {
        if(j==4||i==3)
            return 1;

            if(flag==0)
            {
                printf("\t%d",arr[i][j]);
            }
        function_Matrix(arr,i,j+=1);
        printf("\n");
        function_Matrix(arr,i+=1,j=0);
        flag=1;
    }
    int main()
    {
        int x;
        int arr[][4]={{1,2,3,4},
        {5,6,7,8},
        {9,7,6,5}};
        function_Matrix(arr,0,0);
    }
```

> FLOW!