# Warnings in matrix multiplication using functions

Tags: c, pointers, matrix-multiplication

I'm getting three errors:

1. Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
2. Passing argument 1 of `read` from incompatible pointer type
3. Expected `int * (*)[10]` but argument is of type `int (*)[10][10]`

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read(int *(arr[10][10]), int row, int col) { //Third error here
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
}
void multiply(int arr1[10][10], int row1, int col1,
              int arr2[10][10], int row2, int col2,
              int *prod[10][10]) { //Third error here
    int i, j, k, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < row1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
            temp = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < col1; k++)
                temp += arr1[i][k] * arr2[k][j];
            prod[i][j] = temp; //First error here
        }
}
void display(int arr[10][10], int row, int col) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <col; j++)
            printf("%d\t",arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main() {
    int a[10][10], b[10][10], c[10][10], m, n, p, q, i, j, k;
    printf("Enter the order of matrix A:");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    printf("Enter the order of matrix B:");
    scanf("%d %d", &p, &q);
    if (n != p) {
        printf("Matrix multiplication is not possible.");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Enter the elements of matrix A:\n");
    read(&a, m, n); //Second error here
    printf("Enter the elements of matrix B:\n");
    read(&b, p, q); //Second error here
    multiply(a, m, n, b, p, q, &c);
    printf("Matrix A is:\n");
    display(a, m, n);
    printf("Matrix B is:\n");
    display(b, p, q);
    printf("Product matrix is:\n");
    display(c, m, q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: arrays are not first class objects so you shouldn't just copy what works for `int` and translate it to an array version. This code is very FOOBAR and very hard to explain thoroughly.

Comment: Check for duplicates before asking a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548753/passing-a-multidimensional-variable-length-array-to-a-function

Comment: @user3528438: I'm not sure what you mean by *FOOBAR*, maybe FUBAR? But this would be vastly overstated IMHO. The types are wrong and can easily be fixed, the rest is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `int *(arr[10][10])` for a function argument is not the same as `int arr[10][10]`.  Change the prototype this way:

```
void read_matrix(int arr[10][10], int row, int col)
```

You should not name your function `read` as it is the name of the Posix system call used by the C library to implement the `FILE*` stream interface.  Rename it `read_matrix` and invoke it this way:

```
printf("Enter the elements of matrix A:\n");
read_matrix(a,m,n); //Second error here
printf("Enter the elements of matrix B:\n");
read_matrix(b,p,q); //Second error here
```

The prototype for the matrix multiplication should be changed similarly to:

```
void multiply(int arr1[10][10], int row1, int col1,
              int arr2[10][10], int row2, int col2,
              int prod[10][10])
```

The confusion stems from the way arrays are passed to functions in C: they are passed as a pointer to their first element.  We say that arrays automatically *decay* as pointers when used in expressions and passed as function arguments or return values.  `multiply` should be called this way:

```
multiply(a, m, n, b, p, q, c);
```

Note that you should use braces `{` and `}` for all your `for` loops whose body has more than one line.  Your omitting them for the outer loops in `read` and `multiply` are not strictly incorrect, but error prone and not recommended.

You should also check the return value from `scanf()` and validate the matrix dimensions.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int matrix_read(int arr[10][10], int row, int col) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]) != 1)
                return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int matrix_multiply(int arr1[10][10], int row1, int col1,
                    int arr2[10][10], int row2, int col2,
                    int prod[10][10]) {
    int i, j, k, temp;

    if (col1 != row2)
        return -1;

    for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col2; j++) {
            temp = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < col1; k++) {
                temp += arr1[i][k] * arr2[k][j];
            }
            prod[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void matrix_display(int arr[10][10], int row, int col) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <col; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int a[10][10], b[10][10], c[10][10], m = 0, n = 0, p = 0, q = 0;

    printf("Enter the order of matrix A: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d", &m, &n) != 2 || m < 1 || m > 10 || n < 1 || n > 10) {
        printf("Invalid matrix size: %d x %d.\n", m, n);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter the order of matrix B: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d", &p, &q) != 2 || p < 1 || p > 10 || q < 1 || q > 10) {
        printf("Invalid matrix size: %d x %d.\n", p, q);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (n != p) {
        printf("Matrix multiplication is not possible.");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter the elements of matrix A:\n");
    if (matrix_read(a, m, n)) {
        printf("Invalid matrix data.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter the elements of matrix B:\n");
    if (matrix_read(b, p, q)) {
        printf("Invalid matrix data.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (matrix_multiply(a, m, n, b, p, q, c)) {
        printf("Matrix multiplication error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Matrix A is:\n");
    matrix_display(a, m, n);
    printf("Matrix B is:\n");
    matrix_display(b, p, q);
    printf("Product matrix is:\n");
    matrix_display(c, m, q);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can you tell me how to make changes  to the array I'm passing from main() without using a pointer parameter?

Comment: @SubramanianSridharan: there is no simple way to avoid passing a pointer parameter, nor is it useful.  Defining the function argument as `int arr[10][10]` actually tells the compiler that the function receives a pointer to an array of arrays of 10 ints.  It is equivalent to `int arr[][10]`.  Passing an array of conforming size to the function passes a pointer to its first element. I posted a complete version of the code, check it out.

Comment: Oh thanks! I thought passing the array is similar to passing an integer wherein the changes made to the formal parameters won't reflect in the actual parameters.