# How can I pass a variably sized 2d array to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am generating 3 nxn sized magic squares (Where n is an odd number between 3 and 15), and want to pass the 2d arrays they are stored in to this function:

```
void printSquare(int n, int square[n][n], int b){
    cout << "Magic Square #" << b << " is:\n";

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            printf("%3d ", square[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The arrays are passed to the function like this:

```
 printSquare(n, magicSquare, 1);
```

However, no matter how I try to change it to get the function to accept the 2d array with undefined size, I keep getting errors like "candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'int [n][n]' to 'int (*)[n]' for 2nd argument". How can I fix this so that I can use the 2d array in my function?

Comment: Change language to C? Is that an option?

Comment: How are you generating them?  If you are using a `int**` why not have your function take that?

Comment: Shame on you. https://www.google.com/search?q=How+can+I+pass+a+variably+sized+2d+array+to+a+function pick a duplicate and close the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a multidimensional variable length array to a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548753/passing-a-multidimensional-variable-length-array-to-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

In c++ multi-dimensional arrays need the sizes of all but the top dimension as part of the type. So the type of a 2d array could be int a[][3], but not int a[][].

Assuming that *n* is not a constant, your best bet is to treat *square* as a one dimensional array and then use *n*, which you passed in, to index into *square*, like so:

```
for(int i=0; i<n*n; i++)
{
    printf("%3d ", square[i]);
    if((n-1)==(i%n))
        printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: More complete answers can be found to this duplicate question:
[Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function?rq=1)

Comment: You can use a pointer to a pointer, you don't have to collapse it to a 1D array. i.e. int** in the example above.