# C++: error: invalid types ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}[size_t {aka long unsigned int}]’ for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays

I get the following error when compiling: `error: invalid types ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}[size_t {aka long unsigned int}]’ for array subscript interactionMatrix[i][k]=interaction;`

Here ist the code:

```
void Tree::computeInteractionScore(size_t* interactionMatrix){
  size_t num_independent_variables = data->getNumCols() - no_split_variables->size();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_independent_variables; ++i) {
    for (size_t k = 0; i < num_independent_variables; ++k) {
      size_t interaction = 0;
      if(k!=i){
      //  interaction = computeInteraction(i,k);
      }
      interactionMatrix[i][k]=interaction;
    }
  }
}
```

interactionMatrix is declared as follow:

```
  size_t num_independent_variables = data->getNumCols() - no_split_variables->size();

  size_t interactionMatrix[num_independent_variables][num_independent_variables];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_trees; ++i) {
    trees[i]->computeInteractionScore(&interactionMatrix);
  }
```

Comment: `size_t interactionMatrix[num_independent_variables][num_independent_variables];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays must be declared using compile-time expressions to denote the number of entries.  You can just use `std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> interactionMatrix(num_independent_variables, std::vector<size_t>(num_independent_variables));`

Comment: Inside `computeInteractionScore()` you can work with `interactionMatrix` only as a one dimensional array. So you must access the element at `i`th row and `k`th column as `interactionMatrix[i*num_independent_variables + k]`.

Comment: I think a better dup is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548753/passing-a-multidimensional-variable-length-array-to-a-function, as it is more related to VLA-s. Another problem with this code is that OP is passing pointer to this array.

Comment: This is a duplicate question, but it showed up on top in Bing results, and the other question didn't.

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that:

```
size_t interactionMatrix[num_independent_variables][num_independent_variables];
```

is VLA (Variable Length Array) because `size_t` is non const, so it is non standard extension which by default is enabled under g++. As far as I remember it also allocates memory on stack, so you might end up with stack overflow if your array is too big. I would suggest you to change it to dynamically allocated array (or better a vector of vectors). For example

```
size_t **interactionMatrix; 
interactionMatrix = new int*[num_independent_variables]; 

for (int i = 0; i < num_independent_variables; i++)
    interactionMatrix[i] = new int[num_independent_variables];
```

then your current function parameter type will need to be change to `size_t**`. But then you will need to write your own deallocation code, and to be safe use std::unique_ptr with custom deleter for arrays.

better is to switch to :

```
std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> interactionMatrix(num_independent_variables, std::vector<size_t>(num_independent_variables));
```

and change accordingly function signature.

Comment: That's not right. He's passing a 2-dimensional array, not an array of pointers.