# Segmentation fault using scanf for float ** type

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, segmentation-fault, scanf

I'm trying to code a function that would ask the user to enter matrix. It prompts the number of lines, the number of columns and then prompts the value for each element of the matrix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void enterMatrix(float ** matrix, int nbLines, int nbColumns){
    for (int i = 0; i < nbLines * nbColumns; i++){
        printf("i = %d? ", i);
        scanf("%f", matrix[i]);
    }
}

int main(void){
    int nbLines, nbColumns;
    printf("nbLines? "); scanf("%d", &nbLines);
    printf("nbColumns? "); scanf("%d", &nbColumns);
    float *matrix[nbL * nbCol];

    enterMatrix(matrix, nbLines, nbColumns);
}
```

Everything works fine until I enter a value for `i = 0` and then press <kbd>enter</kbd>, which leads to a segmentation fault.

Any idea as to what could be wrong?

Comment: `float *matrice[nbL * nbCol];` => `float matrice[nbL * nbCol];` no need for pointers. but you have to pass the dimensions to `enterMatrix` somehow.

Comment: read about passing VLAs to functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548753/passing-a-multidimensional-variable-length-array-to-a-function

Comment: What is **matrix** in enterMatrix function?

Comment: when you translate your code, please make it so as it compiles :)

Comment: Note that `scanf()` can fail, if the input doesn't parse as the expected type. It's a good idea to check the return value.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry I didn't translate properly! I've edited the code

Comment: `nbL` and `nbCol` are undeclared identifiers. Please copy and past the exact code you were using

Comment: See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate memory dinamically since you do not know at compile time which values the variables `nbLines` and `nbColumns` will hold.

So you need to first declare the pointer to the matrix:

```
float **matrix;
```

Then start allocate memory according to user input:

```
matrix = (float **)malloc(nbLines * sizeof(float *));

for (int i = 0; i < nbLines; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = (float *)malloc(nbColums * sizeof(float ));
}
```

The segmentation fault error happens becouse you are not allocating memory for your matrix, but just a `[nbL * nbCol]` pointers to `float`

Comment: This suggests that matrices should be implemented as arrays of pointers, which is not good - it's probably better to implement matrices as dynamically allocated arrays of `float`

Comment: Also, in C, the type conversions of results of `malloc()` are not required (and are actively discouraged as bad technique - if `#include <stdlib.h>` has been forgotten, the conversions obscure that AND result in undefined behaviour).    It is also considered better to avoid hard-coding the type in the `malloc()` call   e.g. use `matrix = malloc(nbLines * sizeof (*matrix))` rather than `matrix = malloc(nbLines * sizeof (float *))` since the latter will break if the definition of `matrix` changes ... such as to a `double **`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is because

```
float *matrice[nbL * nbCol];
```

defines an array of uninitialised pointers (i.e. an array of `float *`), not an array of float.    This is then passed to `enterMatrix()` as a pointer to pointer to `float` (i.e. a `float **`).   The `scanf()` calls then read to `matrix[i]` which is an uninitialised pointer.   The result is undefined behaviour.

One fix would be to change the definition of `matrice` in `main()` to

```
float matrice[nbL * nbCol];
```

and change the function to  (I've used comment to highlight changes)

```
void enterMatrix(float *matrix, int nbLines, int nbColumns)    /*  note type of matrix  */
{
     for (int i = 0; i < nbLines * nbColumns; i++)
     {
         printf("i = %d? ", i);
         scanf("%f", &matrix[i]);      /*  note what the second argument is */
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't allocate enough memory for your array, thus you invoke Undefined Behavior, since you go out of bounds, causing a Segmentation fault.

You could declare it like a 2D array, like this:

```
/* TODO: Check if allocation succeeded. (check for NULL pointer) */
float** matrix;
matrix = malloc(nbLines * sizeof(float*));
for(int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(nbColumns * sizeof(float));
```

I have other approaches for allocating a 2D array dynamically [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/2d-dynamic-array-c/).

Please note: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No!

Also do not forget to `free()`.

---

You could emulate a 2D array with an 1D array, like this:

```
void enterMatrix(float* matrix, int nbLines, int nbColumns){
    for (int i = 0; i < nbLines ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nbColumns; j++) {
        scanf("%f", matrix[i + nbColumns * j]);
    }
}
float matrix[nbLines * nbColumns];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a variable length array, and, of *pointers*.

While other answers are perfectly valid, if you *really* want a 2D array, you just need to change the declaration:

```
float matrix[nbLines][nbColumns];
```

to declare a 2D variable length array of floats.

Now the hard point is to pass this VLA to a function and preserve dimensions.

For that you could use C99 way of passing VLAs (note that dimensions must be located before the VLA itself). Reference: [Passing a multidimensional variable length array to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548753/passing-a-multidimensional-variable-length-array-to-a-function):

```
void enterMatrix(int nbLines, int nbColumns, float matrix[][nbColumns] ){
    for (int i = 0; i < nbLines; i++){
       for (int j = 0; j < nbColumns; j++)
   {            
        scanf("%f", &matrix[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

call as follows:

```
    enterMatrix(nbLines, nbColumns, matrix);
```

Comment: @M.M I fixed one issue: the declaration. My eyes deceived me in the first place... yeah, also the `scanf` argument... thanks for the revert!!

Comment: note that my blurb wasn't very accurate. Thanks for pointing those mistakes.