# How do I print out a 2D array that is initialized in function main in C?

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, printf, 2d

```
void print2DArray(int aRRay[][COLS], int r, int c);
int main()
{
    int aRRay[ROWS][COLS];
    int n;

    int r, c;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
        {
            aRRay[r][c] = -40 + rand() % (80 + 1 - (-40));
        }
    }

print2DArray(aRRay[r][c], r, c);

printf("Enter an integer between -40 and 80: \n");
scanf("%d", &n);
while (n >= 40 || n <= -80)
{
    printf("Thie is an invalid integer, please re-enter an integer between 
     -80 and 40");
    scanf("%d", &n);
}

return 0;
}
void print2DArray(int aRRay[][COLS], int r, int c) 
statement
{
int j, k;
for (j = 0; j < ROWS; j++)
{
    for (k = 0; k < COLS; k++)
    {
        printf("%d ", aRRay[r][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

How do I print out a 2D array that is initialized in function main in C? 
How do I get the function to work? I'm supposed to use the random number generator to create the numbers for my 2D array and then print it out in a void function.

Comment: Review `for (k = 0; k < COLS; k++)
    {
        printf("%d ", aRRay[r][c]);`.  Why `c` in `aRRay[r][c])`?

Comment: I'm confused on what to type inside of my print function to get aRRay[r][c] to print with the random numbers I initialized in function main

Comment: You'll have to start by de-obfuscating the code and use proper indention.

Answer (score 0):

int your last fonction `{printf("%d ", aRRay[r][c]); }` do this instead `{printf("%d ", aRRay[j][k]); }`. Because you are doing a loop but you are not using your loop to do anything, so use the j and k to loop in your printf. Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I print out a 2D array ...?

OP's code is amiss:

```
// printf("%d ", aRRay[r][c]);
printf("%d ", aRRay[j][k]);
```

How it is initialized/assigned is not so important.  Pass the dimensions to the print function first and then the array.

Array dimensions are best typed as `size_t` than `int`.

```
// C99 solution using a variable length array

void print2DArray(size_t rows, size_t cols, int aRRay[rows][cols]) {
  for (size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      printf("%d ", aRRay[r][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Sample use

```
#define ROWS 6
#define COLS 7

int main() {
  int aRRay[ROWS][COLS];
  size_t r, c;
  int n = 0;
  for (r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
    for (c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
      aRRay[r][c] = ++n;
    }
  }
  print2DArray(ROWS, COLS, aRRay);
  int bRRay[2][3] = {{11,12,13}, {14,15,16}};
  print2DArray(2,3, bRRay);
}
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
22 23 24 25 26 27 28 
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 
36 37 38 39 40 41 42 
11 12 13 
14 15 16
```

OP had "I'm supposed to use the random number generator to create the numbers for my 2D array " which is fine.  The above use `++n` as it is more illustrative.

See also [Passing a multidimensional variable length array to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14548753/2410359).