# Why are the consecutive rows not being printed from this 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a program which prints out a board with the letters abcd... as a coordinate system and with 'U's as the tiles. When I used a dynamically allocated 2D array it worked fine. Now that I've changed it to a static array, the program prints out gibberish (all the rows should be the same as the first one).
I know all functions are working properly except the printRow or printBoard functions.

Something I've realized is that, depending on the size of the board, I get a different number of rows (4 prints 1, 6 prints 2, 8 prints 3, etc)

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


//Prints a row of the board given the row number
void printRow(int n, int row, char board[][26]) {
    int column;
    for (column = 0; column < n; column++) {
        printf("%c", board[row][column]);
        }
    }

//Prints the whole board, including the coordinate system
void printBoard (char board[][26], int n) {
    //Print top letters
    int character = 97, letter;
    printf("  ");
    for (letter = 0; letter < n; letter++) {
        printf("%c", character + letter);
        }
    printf("\n");
    //Reinitialize to print side letters
    int row = 0;
    for (letter = 0; letter < n; letter++, row++) {
        printf("%c ", character + letter);
        printRow(n, row, board);
        printf("\n");
        }
    }

bool positionInBounds(int n, int row, int col) {
    //Checks to see if letters are greater than max letter or less than a
    if (row - 97 >= n || col - 97 >= n || row - 97 < 0 || col - 97 < 0) {
        return false;
        }
    else {
        return true;
        }
    }

void boardConfig(char board[][26], int n) {
    printf("Enter board configuration: \n");
    char input[20];
    int check = 1;
    while (check == 1) {
        gets(input);
        if (input[0] == '!' && input[1] == '!' && input[2] == '!') {
            check = 0;
            }
        if (positionInBounds(n, input[1], input[2])) {
            board[input[1]-97][input[2]-97] = input[0];
            }
        }
    }




/*bool checkLegalInDIrection(char board[][26], int n, int row, int col, char colour, int deltaRow, int deltaCol) {

    }
*/
int main(void)
{

    int n;
    printf("Enter the board dimension: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //Dynamically allocate array and initialize all board positions to default 'U'
    /*char **board = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        board[row] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
        }
*/
    char board[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            board[i][j] = 'U';
            }
        //Set board to default starting positions
        board[n/2-1][n/2-1] = 'W';
        board[n/2-1][n/2] = 'B';
        board[n/2][n/2-1] = 'B';
        board[n/2][n/2] = 'W';
        }

    boardConfig(board, n);
    printBoard(board, n);


    return 0;
}
```

This is the 
[current output for an 8 x 8 board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wPHt.png):

Edit: I realize a dynamic array would be easier to use (that's what I did initially) but this is an assignment and we are explicitly asked to use a static array.I set the board to have a maximum of 26 columns because there are a maximum of 26 letters. We must create a function that takes in board[][26] regardless of the size of the actual board. It must look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RnzZ.png).

Comment: I believe it is because you lied to the compiler. `char board[][26]` That tells the compiler that you will pass in an array where the second dimension is `26` but that's not really what you pass in.

Comment: @kaylum Yea I've realized when I print out a 26 x 26 board it works fine. Is there a way to pass a static 2d array without knowing the size before runtime?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a multidimensional variable length array to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548753/passing-a-multidimensional-variable-length-array-to-a-function)

Comment: Not sure about the assignment requirements but another option is just to always declare the board as max size: `char board[26][26];`. Then the functions will be correct. It just means some of the board entries may not be used.

Comment: @kaylum I'm afraid it doesn't. I edited my post with an image to show how the function must look, although I'm afraid it's not doable. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: How about my other comment? It seems the prof wants the full board defined even if not all used. Or perhaps `char board[n][26]`.

Comment: @kaylum That doesn't seem to work either.